# Commerce crashing after longer inactivity

Tags: sitecore-commerce, iis

We are using Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2. On our test server, usually after a weekend (thus assumption that the inactivity time is significant factor here) the Commerce responds with a InvalidShopCurrency error to all requests. The environment is not functional until iisreset. The first error occurrence is preceded with the error below. The log comes from Authoring instance. Any ideas for a fix?

All Commerce app pools on the IIS have Idle Time-out set to 0.

```
48 09:11:11 INFO Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/GetList(id='Catalogs',type='Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.Catalog,%20Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog',skip=0,take=1000)?$expand=Items($expand=Components($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents)))  
7 09:11:11 INFO Authorization was successful for user: null.
48 09:11:11 INFO MemCache.CreateCache.HabitatAuthoring.Items
48 09:11:11 INFO Management.block.getitembypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront|en
48 09:11:11 INFO Management.block.getitembypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront: Language=en
37 09:11:11 INFO MemCache.CreateCache.HabitatAuthoring.ItemsCollection
39 09:11:11 INFO Management.block.getitemsbypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront|en
14 09:11:11 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Core.block.GetEnvironmentCache ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Core.GetEnvironmentCacheBlock.Run(EnvironmentCacheArgument arg, CommercePipelineExecutionContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
33 09:11:11 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Core.block.GetEnvironmentCache ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Core.GetEnvironmentCacheBlock.Run(EnvironmentCacheArgument arg, CommercePipelineExecutionContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
14 09:11:11 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Management.block.getitemsbypath ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Framework.Caching.SitecoreCacheExtensions.<Get>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.GetItemsByPathBlock.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
33 09:11:11 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Management.block.getitemsbypath ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Framework.Caching.SitecoreCacheExtensions.<Get>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.GetItemsByPathBlock.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
33 09:11:11 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Management.block.PopulateShop ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.PopulateShopBlock.<GetConfigurationItem>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.PopulateShopBlock.<Run>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
14 09:11:11 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Management.block.PopulateShop ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.PopulateShopBlock.<GetConfigurationItem>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.PopulateShopBlock.<Run>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
14 09:11:11 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.InvalidShopCurrency: Text=Currency 'USD' for Shop 'CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront' was not found.
```

Comment: Check and test your 'Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionPolicy' in Plugin.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json.
Make sure the host/username/domain/password/protocol...are correct. Commerce Engine is probably not able to talk to Sitecore.

Answer (score 2):

I had run into similar issue as I see at the bottom of the stack trace you have posted :
**CtxMsg.Error.InvalidShopCurrency: Text=Currency 'USD' for Shop 'CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront' was not found.**

Turned out that my Sitecore license had expired. Have you checked that? Just a thought, but sometimes we miss the obvious.

Also, checkout the blog post by Late Ryan Bailey: https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/02/sitecore-experience-commerce-commerce.html

Best,
Hetal